# Installing Ioncube loaders without issues CentOS 5.9

Tags: centos, software-installation

Seem to be having issues installing Ioncube loaders on CentOS 5.9. I followed [this guide to install Ioncube](http://centos6.info/?p=1):

but it's still not working on the site at all, I keep getting this error on BoxBilling, which is the system that I'm trying to get working:

ionCube loader is required to run BoxBilling. Instructions to [install ionCube loaders](http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php) or [contact support](http://www.boxbilling.com)

No idea why? I've looked around and looked around on google, but there doesn't seem to be many articles on it, I could get it working on CentOS 6.3, but we recently were forced to downgrade, and now I can't get it working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just great, a tarball that users are supposed to drop in the system. And that is supposed to be a CentOS 6 specific package.

Just see if there is a CentOS 5 package around.

[For the record, the fact that this is a **CentOS 6** package, but doesn't use the package system of that distribution at all, is a shrill alarm sign. I'd avoid packages like that like the plague. No dependency management, no sane way to update, no record of the installed package. Toxic.]